# Event seem to get overwritten on timeouts 2nd loop

Tags: jquery, events, timeout, unbind

I've been working on a simple showcase script, and bumped into an issue i cant get past on my own...

First of all, ill paste some code:

```
    obj.timeout = function() {   

        $.doTimeout('showcase', config['timeout'], function() {
            //show preloader
            $.doTimeout('showcase');
            obj.addImage('next');
            var angle = 0;
            setInterval(function(){
                  angle+=3;
                 $(".showcase .preloader").rotate(angle);
            },10);
            $('.showcase .preloader').stop().fadeIn(config['speed']);

            $('.showcase img.next').load(function() {
                $('.showcase .preloader').stop().fadeOut(config['speed']);              
                obj.animateShowcase();
            });         
            return true;

        })
    };


    obj.init = function() {
        //bind events (stop the timer on window blur and showcase hover)

        $(window).bind('blur', function() {
            $.doTimeout('showcase');
        });
        $('section.showcase, .showcase .preloader').bind('mouseover', function() {
            $.doTimeout('showcase'); 
        });

        obj.timeout();   
        obj.loadData();

    };
```

Im using a jquery plugin called jQuery.doTimeout (http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin), which is supposed to make using timout easier (it really did, so far).

Running $.doTimeout( id ) stops a timeout that i previously started with the same id.

The showcase works, animates after the correct delay etc. Im trying to stop it after someone hovers over the showcase, but it only works on the first 'loop'... The timer stops and everything is fine. 
Unfortunately after the timeout function ran at least once, the events seem to unbind themselves... the timeout keeps looping, but the mouseover or blur events stop working...

Ive sat a couple of hours over this, and cant see a solution... Maybe i just need another pair of eyes to look at it!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that if your timeout function is running it always restarts itself at the end via the `return true`. Why don't you set a property `obj.showcase_active = true` and let the timeout function `return obj.showcase_active` instead of `return true`. Then in the mouseover callback, stop the timer and also set `obj.showcase_active = false`.

Comment: Amazing stuff dude! Works like a charm! I just became your biggest fan.. life saver!